# Passing config file and argument to vncviewer

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, vnc, vnc-viewer

I would like to launch vncviewer in a script on Windows.
Using a configuration file works fine:

```
vncviewer.exe /config config.vnc
```

This configuration contains the following:

```
[connection]
host=myvncserver
port=5901
password=encryptedpassword
[options]
restricted=0
viewonly=0
fullscreen=0
```

However I would like to pass the host and port as argument but keeping other options in the conf file. Something like that:

```
vncviewer.exe /config config.vnc myvncserver:5901
```

It doesn't work. A popup opens asking me the password even though it is still defined in the configuration file.

How can I achieve it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `vncviewer.exe -help` does show you all the switches.

So something in this line should work.

```
vncviewer.exe -config config.vnc -ProxyServer vnchost:5901
```